# How can i trigger an Airflow Dag from nodeJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, airflow

I have scenario where the AirFlow Dag updates snowflake tables, and we have a requirement where in i have to trigger the Dag remotely - in our case from NodeJS.
I would like to know if this is possible ?

Comment: you can access by creating API. Refer this https://medium.com/@rako/apache-airflow-as-an-external-scheduler-for-distributed-systems-53b7354d3e48

Answer (score 0):

Airflow’s experimental API does have an endpoint to trigger a dag run, [POST /api/experimental/dags//dag_runs](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/api/client/json_client.py#L23). Otherwise, you could use the probably more stable CLI call to `airflow trigger_dag`, but that might not be possible for you depending on your requirements/setup.